# GetElementsByTagName("Canvas") breaks the 3D Object

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to create a 3D Object where I can let appear things by clicking on specific parts of it. Those are several MESHs placed perfect on/to another and I can turn them on/off, BUT...

I had an issue, that my onDocumentMouseDown function won't be called if I click on my Canvas area. So I used this:

```
kannwases = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas");
kannwas = kannwases[0];
kannwas.addEventListener('mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false);
```

It worked, but if I remove my Object, bring it back again, the other object rotates every time I click on the canvas and perform a small movement, so the Objects aren't attached to each other the way they should.

I have absolutely +-0 ideas what happens there and why. I would be very grateful for any help I get.

Many Thanks in Advance!

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/accneeder/14anutw2/) is the Code...

Comment: i like your variable naming of kannwas :)

Comment: yeah, very creative... thank you :)